# The existence of $ \varphi $ whose sine and cosine are the given numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am studying complex analysis and the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ was defined to be $\mathbb{R}^2$ together with the usual addition in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the multiplication defined by $$(a,b)(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$$

Then by identifying the numbers of the form $(a,0)$ with $a$ (via the homomorphism $i:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $i(a)=(a,0)$), and by representing $(0,1)$ by $i$, I was introduced to the usual notation for complex numbers, in which $(a,b)$ is represented by $a+bi$.

Then to define the polar form of a complex numbers, we observe that for a nonzero complex number, $$a+bi = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$ and from the fact that $\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2 = 1$ it was claimed that there is a $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin(\varphi)= \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\cos(\varphi) = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

My question is exactly that last claim, that is: why is it the case that given two real numbers $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$ there is some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin(\theta)=x$ and $\cos(\theta)=x$. This is easy to be convinced of when we observe that $(x,y)\in S^1$, however, I am looking for an analytic proof of this fact (P.S: the exponential for complex numbers has not yet been constructed).

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin x$ is surjective onto $[-1,1]$ and $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1\,$.

Comment: Got it, very nice! Thanks

Comment: You don’t need the complex exponential yet since the claim is about sine/cosine of a real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ x^2 = 1-y^2 \le 1$ implies $|x| \le 1$. The function $\cos : \mathbb R \to [-1,1]$ is surjective, and so there exists $\theta \in \mathbb R$ such that $\cos \theta = x$.

Next, $y^2 = 1-x^2 = \sin^2 \theta$, so that $y = |\sin \theta|$. If $\sin \theta \ge 0$, then $ \sin \theta = y$ and we are done. If $\sin \theta <0$, then $y = - \sin \theta = \sin(-\theta)$. But then we can take $\psi = - \theta$, so that $\cos \psi = x$ and $\sin \psi = y$ and the claim stil follows.